# How to retrieve and update data from Azure database for a Windows Store App?

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013, windows-store-apps

I have created a simple app which helps in booking the lecture halls in my college. I have 5 days with 5 slots for some lecture hall entered in a table on Azure. Each entry in the table is 1 or 0, accordingly. How do I retrieve these entries as and when required and compare them with user's demand to show whether he/she can book the hall or not?

Comment: Please provide what you've tried so far.

Comment: I am part of a 24-hour hackathon  and I am a beginner.  Azure tutorials aren't helping. Wanted to know where to start and how to start in a clearer way.

Comment: Then you've reached the wrong forum.